# Windows 10 shared folder: Acces Denied (was working before)

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I have a shared folder on my Windows 10 Pro (1607) PC that is accessed by a Windows 10 Family (1607) PC. This setup stopped working overnight (a couple of months back), probably because of an update.

Now I am struggling to make it work again. I feel like I've tried everything:

- With and without Homegroup
- Changed workgroup
- With and without credentials
- Changing the owner of the drive / folder to be shared

Both PCs have the same Admin User that is logged in automatically (via netplwiz). I've gotten to a point where I can see the shares, but not access them.

To test, I created a new share on my desktop, and this one works (!). I tried to find out the differences between the two folders. See the screenshots, the left one is working (Canon) whereas the right one (K) is not working:

[image: Share]
[image: Share]

The only difference I could find was that on the left, the checkboxes are greyed out. Why ?What else can I do ?

This is driving me insane...

Comment: What do your event logs say when access gets denied?

Comment: Where would I see that ? I did not find anything

Comment: Click start, type event logs

Comment: Could not find any reference to this error. I cleared the lists and reproduced it, but nothing new appeared

Comment: If your event logs show *nothing at all* then your client isn't even connecting to the machine at all and cannot be getting an "Access denied" error, more likely "Unreachable" or "Time out"

Comment: It is definitely an Access denied. I also think it might be NTFS related, since the share is the same and the other one works. In which event log category will such an error appear ?

Comment: The logon events would probably be in system or security. I suppose you could turn on additional auditing but it must be something simple I'm missing. The NTFS permissions look basically the same from what you've shown (though I can't read French)

Comment: Could you try renaming the second share (K) and/or creating a new folder under K: and sharing that? I vaguely recall Windows introduced some odd restriction on sharing root folders of drives recently

Comment: I will try that after work, however I have the same issue with another folder. Both are part of a truecrypt container, though...

Comment: Well *that* explains it.... -_- Perhaps should have mentioned that earlier? Truecrypt mounts in a funny way that isn't accessible to all users or even the system in the same way.

Comment: Well, it worked before

Comment: Chances are you mounted it in a different way before. Also depends if it's mounted by system or a local or remote user, at startup, manually, etc. etc. Truecrypt mounting is just another entire can of worms entirely.

Comment: I always mount it manually, that did not change.

Answer (score -1):

For shared folders to work on Windows 10, these steps may help:

a) In Network and sharing center file sharing (network discovery) must be enabled. Turn off password-protected sharing: first make it work simply, then make it work with password protection if necessary.

b) In "Turn Windows features on and off" window (from Run: appwiz.cpl), under "SMB 1.0/CIFS File sharing support", SMB client and server must be enabled.

c) When sharing a folder or a drive, in the properties window on both "Sharing" and "Security" tabs, make sure privileges are given to "All" (other unnecessary entries can be removed). Again, first make it work, then make it work with security.

d) Also, certain services must be enabled but they typically are (you can find which ones in Google). Some suggest than in Network and sharing center network type should be Private and if it can't be changed there, it's possible to set it through a PowerShell command (details can be found on answers.microsoft.com).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any sane user should never enable SMB 1.0 on any machine accessible to the intranet.  **It's insecure, and while the most severe vulnerability was patched, it's not secure and should never be used.**