# Windows 10 access to shared folder

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing, shared-folders

We have several Windows 10 computers on a home network. We can no longer access files in a shared folder, something that used to work. We have not changed user names or passwords recently.

Computer1 shares `C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\Shared\SomeFolder`, and we used to be able to browse this folder from Computer2 as `\\computer1\Shared\SomeFolder`.

At this time, we have functioning shortcuts on Computer2 to a a couple of shared files from Computer1, e.g. `\\computer1\Shared\SomeFolder\File1.xls`. We can read/modify File1.xls from Computer2.

But we cannot browse `\\computer1\Shared`. The error message is:
"Windows cannot access `\\computer1\Shared`. You do not have permissions. Contact your network administrator".

Why is this happening,and how can we fix it?

Comment: To start troubleshooting wise, disable Windows Firewall on comp1 and then try to access share from comp2 again. If it work then you know it's the FW so build in an explicit allow rule for the network range, etc. for the SMB ports, etc. If not then re-enable the FW and then disable AV or other 3rd party FW on the shared server or else aka comp1.

Comment: Since you say you can access files in `\\computer1\Shared\SomeFolder`, you can browse that folder if you write directly that path in the Explorer bar or you get the same error you get with `\\computer1\Shared`?

Comment: I can access files via stored shortcuts (`\\computer1\Shared\SomeFolder\File1.xls`). I cannot browse to `\\computer1\Shared`. Error message as posted

Comment: Please see this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1599183/872215. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can browse the folder using
 `\\computer1\C$\Users\Public\Public Documents\Shared\SomeFolder`